# how to add add values to a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a file as machine.yml:

---

```
machines:  
 A:
    ip: 10.11.12
    pass: vass
    user: A

 B:
    ip: 10.11.13
    pass: grass
    user: B

 C:
    ip: 10.11.14
    pass: pass
    user: C
```

In ruby the file is being parsed as follow:

```
machines = YAML.load_file('machine.yml')
    machines[A].each do |letters,hash|
    ## Iterate through entries in YAML file
    machines.each_value do |machines| 
       var += "[" + hash['user'] + "]\n" + hash['ip'] + "\n"
    end
```

Now, i want to have the values as output as follows:

```
[A]
10.11.12
[B]
10.11.13
[C]
10.11.14
```

But i am not getting output and getting error as

```
"': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"
```

So suggest what shall i do so that i get the following output in a variable, So that the variable can be passed on further to some other function:

```
[A]
10.11.12
[B]
10.11.13
[C]
10.11.14
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in your code.

```
machines[A].each # Where is the variable A defined?

machines.each_value do |machines|  # The variable passed to the block is also machines?

hash['user'] # Where is the variable hash defined?
```

Try this.

```
machines = YAML.load_file('machine.yml')
var = ''
machines.each_value do |hash| 
  var += ("[" + hash['user'] + "]\n" + hash['ip'] + "\n")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work for me via irb:

```
machines['machines'].each {|k,v| p "[" + k + "]" + "\n"  + v["ip"]  }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question. However, when answering questions with code, it is always helpful to also explain how your code works, what is different to what was in in the question and why your code solves the problems it has. Just pasting a snippet of code without further explanation is rarely helpful on its own and might get downvoted or removed later.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses `map` to iterate over the subhashes and `join` to get a multi-line string :

```
require 'yaml'
machines = YAML.load_file('machines.yml')

var = machines['machines'].map{ |id, hash| format("[%s]\n%s", id, hash['ip']) }.join("\n")

puts var
# =>
# [A]
# 10.11.12
# [B]
# 10.11.13
# [C]
# 10.11.14
```